# curl version different in php cli and module

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I just got a new mac running yosemite, and I ran into a problem using curl with combined certificates.  (see this for details: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-10/0053.html)
I compiled version 7.40 of curl and told php to link against it using the --with-curl=/usr/local config option.
Now, after installing and restarting my apache web server, I see that the version in the module is set to 7.37, while the version in the command line is correctly set to 7.40.
Both cli and web server's phpinfo output say the same thing about which php.ini they use:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
```

Yet this is the CLI line for curl:

```
cURL Information => 7.40.0
```

and this is the curl information when running through the apache server:

```
cURL Information    7.37.1
```

How is this possible?  Why does the module link to a different version than the cli?

Answer (score 0):

There's a stock cURL binary and library version 7.37.1 that comes with Yosemite. Your compilation command includes `-L/usr/lib` before `-L/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it links the /usr/lib version in the module and the /usr/local/lib version in the cli build.  Is it because the module does dynamic linking and the cli doesn't?

Comment: use `otool <binary> -L` on both the cli and the PHP module to find out what it was linked against

Comment: Hans' answer is basically correct, but it doesn't explain why the module links against one library and the cli links against a different library.